# Question migrated from SO to SU and then closed there as off-topic

Tags: support, migration, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109556/online-scientific-calculator-closed) was migrated from stackoverflow to superuser and closed there for being off-topic. I really think it is an interesting question, and would like answers to it. Since the site-proposal for web-apps is not through yet, and questions about tools are very common on stackoverflow, I really thought this was the place. How should I proceed? Can it be reopened in some place?

Comment: You'll just have to wait for the Web Apps site. It would be a good question for the beta period so sign up now (if you haven't already) using this handy link http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications?referrer=NuKXZnwd0vA1 (which happens to be my referral link)

Comment: Like I commented: Sorry but web applications aren't allowed on Super User, which is actually a mistake from the guys over at Stack Overflow for even migrating it. However, Wolfram Alpha, as one of the answers suggests is really a great tool for your purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unfortunate side effect of maintaining strong Q&A systems: not every question can be accommodated. Every good Q&A community has to establish their boundaries and maintain them rigorously. Even if your question is truly awesome, it is simply off-topic on all the current systems.

Stack Exchange hopes to [solve your problem](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications).